# Expresión Regular para ignorar una cadena si contiene 4 o mas Mayúsculas consecutivas

Tags: javascript, regex

Buen día,

Solicito de su ayuda porque ya busque en la documentación de expresiones regulares pero no logro hacer una expresión para ignorar toda la cadena si en alguna parte contiene 4 mayúsculas o mas consecutivas. Ya intente varias formas pero no logro hacer que funcione, incluso intente lo siguiente pero están mal:

- `/[^[A-Z]{4,})]/g`
- `/.*(?!([A-Z]{4,}))/g`

Ejemplo de lo que busco conseguir:

**Ignorar toda la siguiente cadena porque la palabra CALIFORNIA tiene mas de 4 Mayúsculas seguidas**

> La Organización de las Naciones Unidas (ONU) es la mayor
> organización internacional existente.
>
> Fue fundada el 24 de octubre de 1945, San Francisco, **CALIFORNIA**, Estados Unidos.

**Permitir toda la cadena porque no tiene ninguna palabra con mas de 4 Mayúsculas seguidas**

> La Organización de las Naciones Unidas (ONU) es la mayor
> organización internacional existente.
>
> Fue fundada el 24 de octubre de 1945, San Francisco, California, Estados Unidos.

En el siguiente enlace estoy haciendo pruebas pero no tengo éxito:
https://regexr.com/60ogv

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba con `/[A-Z]{4}/` detecta 4 mayúsculas consecutivas.

Comment: Incluso si quisieras mostrar alguna especie de "error" (como mysql que te muestra un cachito de texto antes del error) puedes ocupar la regexp que proponen en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260726/two-consecutive-uppercase-letters-from-the-end) del sitio homónimo en inglés.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que entiendo la regex es `/.*[A-Z]{4}.*/gm`

```js
const cadena = "La Organización de las Naciones Unidas (ONU) es la mayor organización internacional existente. \n Fue fundada el 24 de octubre de 1945, San Francisco, CALIFORNIA, Estados Unidos."

const cadena2 = "La Organización de las Naciones Unidas (ONU) es la mayor organización internacional existente. \n Fue fundada el 24 de octubre de 1945, San Francisco, California, Estados Unidos."


const regex =/.*[A-Z]{4}.*/gm;

console.log(regex.test(cadena));//<-- Es verdad que tiene 4 mayúsculas consecutivas

console.log(regex.test(cadena2));//<-- NO es verdad que tiene 4 mayúsculas consecutivas
```